# Matrix manipulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a simple matrix: `[3 5 9 10]`.  How can I transform it to: 
`[3 0 ; 5 3 ; 9 5 ; 10 9]`

I tried using hankel etc. but that did not work.  This needs to be a vector operation (no for/while loop).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. You actually want to use the function [TOEPLITZ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/toeplitz.html) instead:

```
>> vec = [3 5 9 10];
>> toeplitz(vec,[vec(1) 0])

ans =

     3     0
     5     3
     9     5
    10     9
```

However, since you only have 2 columns in your matrix, this is much simpler:

```
[vec; 0 vec(1:end-1)].'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 1:4;

b = repmat(a',1,2);
b(:,2) = b(:,2)-1;
```

Comment: Thanks eykanal! But my Q wasn't clear.. your answer was correct for my initial Q.